# Why is using setState inside componentDidUpdate seen as a bad practice in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint-config-airbnb

I need to update a child's state when a prop gets updated, so I made something like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { searchValue, searchCriterion } = this.props;

    if (searchValue !== prevProps.searchValue) {
      this.setState({ searchValue });
    }
    if (searchCriterion !== prevProps.searchCriterion) {
      this.setState({ searchCriterion });
    }
  }
```

ESLint's airbnb guide is complaining about it and [throwing this warning](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-did-update-set-state.md), even though I can't see any noticeable rendering or performance issues.

The warning says:

> Updating the state after a component update will trigger a second
> render() call and can lead to property/layout thrashing.

Is there a better way to update a child's state when a prop has a new value?

Or should I ignore the warning?

Comment: You can but it will cause an infinite loop if there is no guard. It seems like you use the same value in props and state. Then why putting a state?

Comment: That's a very good point... I don't really need it thanks for pointing it out. However, if there was a case that justifies updating the state according to a prop, is there a way to do it without getting this warning?

Comment: Flagged as warning, you can ignore if you've safely checked that your guards don't create an update cycle. Agree with @bubulledu93 on the storage of the `searchValue` prop. It's a react anti-pattern to duplicate data in props and state. You can simply read `searchValue` from `this.props` where you need it and it won't be delayed a render cycle.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that I'm duplicating data (I'm now using `this.props` in my code), are the equality checks enough to prevent an infinite loop?

Comment: It seems there are multiple articles on the subject like https://itnext.io/how-to-updating-state-on-prop-changes-2296a03ef08c. It depends on the situation. Hooks make it easier with `useEffect`

Answer (score 1):

The problem of your code is that it might create an infinite loop. When you call the `setState` method, you trigger a second `render`, just like the warning says, and consequently a new `componentDidUpdate`.

In order to solve this problem, you might want to create a break condition for certain values of your state to get out of your loop. For example, you could simply use a flag like so:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
const { searchValue, searchCriterion } = this.props;

if (this.state.isAlreadyUpdated === true) {
  this.setState({ isAlreadyUpdated: false });
  break;
} else {
  this.setState({ isAlreadyUpdated: true });
}

if (searchValue !== prevProps.searchValue) {
  this.setState({ searchValue });
}
if (searchCriterion !== prevProps.searchCriterion) {
  this.setState({ searchValue });
}
```

}

Comment: I see what you're doing here and how it can prevent an infinite loop, thanks for the explanation on the flag!